# Given an array of timestamps, a sample frequency and a offset, create the set of all possible timestamps

Tags: python

Given an array of timestamps

```
 l = [Timestamp('2019-10-29 15:30:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
     Timestamp('2019-10-29 20:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
     Timestamp('2019-10-29 21:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
     Timestamp('2019-10-29 21:15:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
```

And if I also have an look-back window size (offset) which should be user defined in minutes, for instance `T = 30`, and a user defined sample frequency in minutes, for instance `f=15` what is a good way to create all possible timestamps?

```
 def create_all_timestamps(list_of_ts,window_size,f):
    ## do some stuff
    return all_ts_values
```

The expected output in this case would be

```
 create_all_timestamps(l,window_size=30,f=15)

 [Timestamp('2019-10-29 15:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'), ## 15:30 - 30 min
 Timestamp('2019-10-29 15:15:00+0000', tz='UTC'),  ## 15:30 - 15 min
 Timestamp('2019-10-29 15:30:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2019-10-29 19:30:00+0000', tz='UTC'),  # 20:00 - 30 min
 Timestamp('2019-10-29 19:45:00+0000', tz='UTC'),  # 20:00 - 15 min
 Timestamp('2019-10-29 20:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
 Timestamp('2019-10-29 20:30:00+0000', tz='UTC'),  # 21:00 - 30 min 
 Timestamp('2019-10-29 20:45:00+0000', tz='UTC'),  # 21:00 - 15 min (21:15 - 30 min also)
 Timestamp('2019-10-29 21:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),  
 Timestamp('2019-10-29 21:15:00+0000', tz='UTC')]
```

If I had set a `T < f` then the original list would be returned, because all possible timestamps are already there given the sample frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my own answer using the `pd.date_range` function as suggested by anarchy in other answer.

```
def get_all_timestamps(ts_l,f,w):
    if w < 2*f:
        return ts_l
    else:
        output = []
        for ts in ts_l:
            p = int(np.floor(w/f))+1
            output.extend(list(pd.date_range(ts, periods=p, freq="-{}T".format(f))))
    return list(sorted(list(set(output))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work,

You can specify the start time like this,

```
pd.date_range("2019-10-29 15:00:00", periods=3, freq="900S")
```

your output will look like this,

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-10-29 15:00:00', '2019-10-29 15:15:00',
               '2019-10-29 15:30:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='900S')
```

You can also set the timezone using the `tz` flag.

So I put all the requirements you wanted, here is what it would look like,

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

#first timestamp is the beginning, 
#second number in each list of list tells howmany periods you want after.
# the third number is howmany minutes you want to set before
stamps = [["2019-10-29 15:00:00",3,30],
          ['2019-10-29 20:00:00',4,30],
          ['2019-10-29 21:00:00',3,30],
          ['2019-10-29 21:15:00']]

x = pd.DataFrame()

for i in stamps[:-1]:
    timestart = datetime.datetime.strptime(i[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - datetime.timedelta(seconds=i[2]*60)
#next line you set howmany periods before the timestamp to add
    x = x.append(pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(timestart, periods=2, freq="900S")))
#next line you set howmany periods after the timpstamp to add
    x = x.append(pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(i[0], periods=i[1], freq="900S")))

x = x[x>=stamps[0][0]].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
x = x[x<=stamps[-1][0]].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
x = x.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
print(x)
```

My output looks like this,

```
                     0
0  2019-10-29 15:00:00
1  2019-10-29 15:15:00
2  2019-10-29 15:30:00
3  2019-10-29 19:30:00
4  2019-10-29 19:45:00
5  2019-10-29 20:00:00
6  2019-10-29 20:15:00
7  2019-10-29 20:30:00
8  2019-10-29 20:45:00
9  2019-10-29 21:00:00
10 2019-10-29 21:15:00
```

You can convert it to a series, a list or rename the column as you wish.

Comment: No, this would also include values that are not present in the expected output.

Comment: @kspr i updated my answer, does this work for you?

Comment: No, you are including a lot of values which are not present in the expected output. I only want to include timestamps which are within the lookback window of any of the original timestamps. For instance, anything around 4 pm is not wanted if you look at expected output..

Comment: If it is not matching the expected output it's not a correct solution for the problem at hand. I do believe that pd.date_range can be a good component in a solution.

Comment: hold on.. ill give you the whole answer

Comment: @kspr okay i have checked your answer any mine, i have the exact same timestamps, is it okay now ?

Comment: It works, but I believe I came up with maybe a more clean function for this.